# fetching data from the Dog API using axios and saving data into a new array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, next.js

I'm on a NextJS app, using Typescript, at the moment and my problem is on the functionality side: I'm using the Dog API to fetch all the breeds names and save them inside a new array of arrays that contain the breeds as keys and the URL images (that I get with another fetch request to the API) as values.

I've tried two separate functions one getting the breeds storing them onto a list using useState() which works, and at the same time, calling inside my component the function that fetches the image for that breed with the .map method etc. That last part didn't work.

```
const BreedSelectorBox: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState<Array<string>>([]);

  const fetchBreedsList = async () => {
    const res: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(
      "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all"
    );
    const breedList: Array<string> = [];
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(res.data.message)) {
      breedList.push(key);
    }
    const breedListImages: string[] = breedList.map(async (breed) => {
      const image: string = await axios
        .get(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
        .then((res) => res.data.message);
      return { key: breed, value: image };
    });
    // setBreeds(breedList);
    console.log(breedListImages);
  };

  const fetchBreedRandomImage = async (breed: string) => {
    const res: AxiosResponse = await axios.get(
      `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`
    );
    return res.data.message;
  };

  return (
    <Box
```

On the first try, I used the results from my breeds variable and with .map iterated through every breed in the hope of adding the fetchBreedRandomImage() function and getting an image URL/string back but I wasn't getting anything because that function apparently returns a promise and not a string and so no image is being displayed.

My next idea was with the breedListImages() function in which I'm trying to do that outside of my component and create an array of arrays as described above and it returns something like that with which I can not work or don't know how to: [image]

Any ideas on how to approach my problem? Also If you notice anything wrong in regards to my Typescript, that's my first attempt so you've been warned!

---

---

After trying @Phil solution/function which was perfect and thank you for that: [image]
I got this error: [image]

And I'm also using these snippets of code to render the image to the my component:

```
<ImageList
        sx={{
          width: 500,
          height: 450,
          // Promote the list into its own layer in Chrome. This costs memory, but helps keeping high FPS.
          transform: "translateZ(0)",
        }}
        rowHeight={200}
        gap={1}
      >
        {breeds &&
          breeds.map((breed) => {
            const cols = breed.featured ? 2 : 1;
            const rows = breed.featured ? 2 : 1;
/// try to ignore those lines with const cols and rows

            return (
              <ImageListItem key={breed.key} cols={cols} rows={rows}>
                <img
                  src={breed.value}
                  alt={breed.key}
                  // loading="lazy"
                  width={250}
                  height={200}
                />
                <ImageListItemBar
                  sx={{
                    background:
                      "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 0%, " +
                      "rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 70%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%)",
                  }}
                  title={breed}
                  position="top"
                  actionIcon={
                    <IconButton
                      sx={{ color: "white" }}
                      aria-label={`star ${breed}`}
                    >
                      <StarBorderIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  }
                  actionPosition="left"
                />
              </ImageListItem>
            );
          })}
      </ImageList>
```

How do I get out of this? Thanks again!

---

---

The way out of my last error was to set my src,alt etc attributes in my code right, so nothing wrong with Phil's answer! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your typing is incorrect. `breedListImages` is not `string[]` but in fact...

```js
Array<Promise<{ key: string, value: string }>>
```

This is because `async` functions like your `.map()` callback return promises.

You'd need to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all those promises to resolve before setting your state.

Here's a cleaned up version with some nicer interfaces defined...

```js
// this matches `{ key: breed, value: image }` from your question
interface DogBreed {
  key: string,
  value: string
}

interface ListAllResponse {
  message: {
    [ key: string ]: string[]
  }
}

interface ImageResponse {
  message: string
}

const BreedSelectorBox: FunctionComponent = () => {
  // state is an array of DogBreed types
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState<DogBreed[]>([]);

  const fetchBreedsList = async () => {
    // fetch all breeds. Axios requests can be typed for the response
    const { data: { message: allBreeds } } = await axios.get<ListAllResponse>(
      "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all"
    );

    // extract keys from the ListAllResponse.message
    const keys = Object.keys(allBreeds)

    // resolve images and create DogBreed objects
    const dogBreeds = await Promise.all(keys.map(async key => {
      const { data: { message: value } } = await axios.get<ImageResponse>(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${encodeURIComponent(key)}/images/random`
      )
      return { key, value }
    }))

    // console.log(dogBreeds)
    setBreeds(dogBreeds)
  };
```